# Ansible nested loop dependency

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to submit a request to a service API, and later query the status before making other calls.

In this example, I'm trying to make API for (CallOne, CallTwo), which type of loop I should be looking for? I have tried nested forloop, but I couldn't get loop dependency to work, I'm not sure if ansible supports such loop.

```
- name: API - callOne
  uri:
    url: "https://localhost/api/commands/callOne"
    method: POST
    user: "admin"
    password: "admin"
  register: callOne
  delegate_to: localhost

- name: API - callOne - awating async task to complete
  uri:
    url: "https://localhost/api/commands/{{callOne.json['id']}}"
    method: GET
    user: "admin"
    password: "admin"
  register: callOne_repsonse
  until: callOne_repsonse.json.active == false and callOne_repsonse.json.success == true
  retries: 10
  delay: 15
  delegate_to: localhost

- debug: msg={{callOne_repsonse.json.resultMessage}}



- name: API - callTwo
  uri:
    url: "https://localhost/api/commands/callTwo"
    method: POST
    user: "admin"
    password: "admin"
  register: callTwo
  delegate_to: localhost

- name: API - callTwo - awating async task to complete
  uri:
    url: "https://localhost/api/commands/{{callTwo.json['id']}}"
    method: GET
    user: "admin"
    password: "admin"
  register: callTwo_repsonse
  until: callTwo_repsonse.json.active == false and callTwo_repsonse.json.success == true
  retries: 10
  delay: 15
  delegate_to: localhost

- debug: msg={{callTwo_repsonse.json.resultMessage}}
```

Comment: it is not clear what is the additional condition on the second call that depends on the first call execution; also you said you tried with nested loops, but i don't see any existing loop in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand of your question (unsure it's the case as you talk about dependency but none is obvious in your question), I guess a solution would be something like that:

```
- name: API - call
  uri:
    url: "https://localhost/api/commands/{{ item }}"
    method: POST
    user: "admin"
    password: "admin"
  register: call
  delegate_to: localhost
  with_items:
    - callOne
    - callTwo

- name: API - awaiting async task to complete
  uri:
    url: "https://localhost/api/commands/{{ item.json.id }}"
    method: GET
    user: "admin"
    password: "admin"
    register: call_response
  until: call_response.json.active == false and call_response.json.success == true
  retries: 10
  delay: 15
  delegate_to: localhost
  with_items: "{{ call.results }}"

- debug: msg={{ item.json.resultMessage }}
  with_items: "{{ call_response.results }}"
```